# authenticating en external client in Pine script

Tags: authentication, pine-script, algorithmic-trading

I'm in the process of writing an indicator that has Open Interest as a confirmation. However, in order to retrieve the Open Interest Chart, I need to be authenticated using the Coinalyze API (as this information is not freely available on Tradingview.com). However first off all, I can't see in Pinescript's documentation whether authenticating with a username/password combination is possible in the first place.

Does anybody know if this is doable? I also haven't found the api method to authenticate or retrieve the open interest data either, but knowing if authentication is possible in the first place would be helpful first.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

no it is not possible to do this type of operation directly from pine at this time. You are best to do this from something like python and if you would still like to use TV, then you could use python or an equivalent as an intermediary.

Cheers!

Comment: Cheers, thanks for clearing this up! I guess I have to switch it up indeed...

Comment: I work several strategies from pine to API’s through my python app and it works great!